# Lightning Component - data binding not working on sObject [] for new element pushed in array

Tags: lightning-aura-components, iteration

If I load a sObject array in init function, I m getting my array correctly filled and loaded to the UI using iteration. I create a new button to add (push) new element of the same type to the existing array. When I fill the value of ui:inputText and push the button to add a 2nd element, the first element is unbind (value is reset to empty) and so one upon element creation. For all elements loaded at the beginning the data are still binded and can be modified even after several add clicks.

CODE:

```
<aura:component >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<!--DATA MODEL: Test__c with only Name as text field-->
<aura:attribute name="alltests" type="Test__c[]" />

<aura:iteration items="{!v.alltests}" var="aTest" >
    <span>
        <ui:inputText  value="{!aTest.Name}"/>
    </span>
</aura:iteration>

<button  type="button"  onclick="{!c.add}">Add button</button>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
doInit : function(c, e, h) {
    var alltests = c.get("v.alltests");
    // Normally I load array from database data but fo the eample I only fill it with hard coded values
    alltests.push( {'sobjectType': 'Test__c', 'Name':'value 1'} );
    alltests.push( {'sobjectType': 'Test__c', 'Name':'value 2'} );
    alltests.push( {'sobjectType': 'Test__c', 'Name':'value 3'} );

    c.set("v.alltests", alltests);
},
/////////////////
 add : function(c, e, h) { // Hooked to new element button on UI
    var alltests = c.get("v.alltests");

    alltests.push( {'sobjectType': 'Test__c', 'Name':''} ); // Input is loaded blank and should be filled by user

    c.set("v.alltests", alltests);
}
//////////////////
})
```

[image]

Step 1: Inputs loaded => OK

Step 2: Push Add button then modification of values => OK

Step 3: Modification of the 4th input(the new one) => OK

Step 4: Push Add button => KO: values of new element is unbinded / erased

This drive me crazy because it's a basic use case.

Please help me it quite urgent.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As an alternative to the answer below you can also try using -> c.set("v.alltests", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(alltests)));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue with locker service enabled.Looks like a bug in LC.

As a workaround, you could create new instance of the array and set it to `alltests` aura:attribute.

So replace below line in the `add` method:

```
 c.set("v.alltests", alltests);
```

By this line:

```
c.set("v.alltests", [].concat(alltests));
```

So your add method will look like this:

```
 add : function(c, e, h) { // Hooked to new element button on UI
    var alltests = c.get("v.alltests");

    alltests.push( {'sobjectType': 'Test__c', 'Name':''} ); // Input is loaded blank and should be filled by user

    c.set("v.alltests", [].concat(alltests)); // create new instance of array everytime 
}
```

**P.S** : Also, I would encourage you to raise a case with sf support.So that they can fix this issue in the framework.